# Number theory/combinatorial proof for cycliclity of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I have tried everything I could and I think I'm conceding. I am trying to find a prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic without using FTFAG and theory of finite fields.

Does anyone have a nice combinatorial/number theory proof they know of?

Edit: I would even be satisfied with a linear algebra/analysis proof.

Comment: I don't know, but I would bet any number-theortic proof would be equivalent to the one using FTFAG and fields.

Comment: Any possibilities for an analysis proof?

Comment: I don't see why there would be an analytic proof.

Comment: Here is [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057893/how-to-show-the-existence-of-a-primitive-root-modulo-p) using Möbius function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to avoid the FTFAG?

Comment: @Ben just for the sake of collecting more proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course,  the group has order $\varphi (p)=p-1$.  I would suggest consulting Gauß's *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* (1801), where he is supposed to have given two proofs of the existence of primitive elements (one constructive).  I believe this would do it, as you would then have an element of order $p-1$.